# MySQL count / track streaks or consecutive dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

```
+-----+------------+------------+---------------------+
| id  | seller_id  | prod_id    | date                |
+-----+------------+----------------------------------+
|   1 | 283        | 4243       | 2016-10-10 23:55:01 |
|   2 | 287        | 4243       | 2016-10-10 02:01:06 |
|   3 | 283        | 4243       | 2016-10-11 23:55:06 |
|   4 | 311        | 4243       | 2016-10-11 23:55:07 |
|   5 | 283        | 4243       | 2016-10-12 23:55:07 |
|   6 | 283        | 4243       | 2016-10-13 23:55:07 |
|   7 | 311        | 4243       | 2016-10-13 23:55:07 |
|   8 | 287        | 4243       | 2016-10-14 23:57:06 |
|   9 | 311        | 4243       | 2016-10-14 23:57:06 |
|  10 | 311        | 4243       | 2016-10-15 23:57:06 |
+-----+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

From the table above how would I extract the following information using an MySQL query?

```
+------------+---------+----------------+---------------+
| seller_id  | prod_id | streak in days | begin streak  | 
+-----+------------+--------------------+---------------+
| 283        | 4243    | 4              | 2016-10-10    |
| 287        | 4243    | 1              | 2016-10-10    |
| 311        | 4243    | 1              | 2016-10-11    |
| 311        | 4243    | 3              | 2016-10-13    |
| 287        | 4243    | 1              | 2016-10-14    |
+------------+---------+----------------+---------------|
```

So basically I need to identify each block of consecutive dates for each seller (seller_id) selling products (prod_id).

I limited this example to 1 prod_id and only a range of a few days, but sellers do sell more than 1 product (prod_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  seller_id
  ,prod_id
  ,COUNT(*) as StreakInDays
  ,MIN(DateCol) as BeginStreak
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      seller_id
      ,prod_id
      ,DATE(DateCol) as DateCol
      ,(@rn:= if((@seller = seller_id) AND (@prod = prod_id), @rn + 1,
                 if((@seller:= seller_id) AND (@prod:= prod_id), 1, 1)
                  )
        ) as RowNumber
    FROM
      Transact t
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seller:=0, @prod:=0, @rn:=0) var
    ORDER BY
      seller_id
      ,prod_id
      ,DATE(DateCol)
    ) t    
GROUP BY
  seller_id
  ,prod_id
  ,DATE_SUB(DateCol, INTERVAL RowNumber Day)
ORDER BY
  prod_id
  ,DATE_SUB(DateCol, INTERVAL RowNumber Day)
  ,seller_id
```

Generate a partitioned row number partitioned by seller_id and prod_id.  Then use the Date - RownNumber as a grouping and you can get to your answer by simple aggregation.

SQL Fiddle to show you it works for multiple products, sellers etc. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a0c44/8/0

Note if it is possible that the same seller can have more than 1 transaction for a product on the same day then you will need to replace the Transact with a derived table of DISTINCT seller_id, prod_id, DATE(date) before generating the row number like this:

```
SELECT
  seller_id
  ,prod_id
  ,COUNT(*) as StreakInDays
  ,MIN(DateCol) as BeginStreak
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      seller_id
      ,prod_id
      ,DateCol
      ,(@rn:= if((@seller = seller_id) AND (@prod = prod_id), @rn + 1,
                 if((@seller:= seller_id) AND (@prod:= prod_id), 1, 1)
                  )
        ) as RowNumber
    FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT seller_id, prod_id, DATE(DateCol) as DateCol
       FROM
         Transact
      )t
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seller:=0, @prod:=0, @rn:=0) var
    ORDER BY
      seller_id
      ,prod_id
      ,DateCol
    ) t    
GROUP BY
  seller_id
  ,prod_id
  ,DATE_SUB(DateCol, INTERVAL RowNumber Day)
ORDER BY
  prod_id
  ,DATE_SUB(DateCol, INTERVAL RowNumber Day)
  ,seller_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a0c44/11

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted. I have one small issue though which messes up the count, namely: 
Sometimes there are multiple entries on 1 day for a certain seller_id / prod_id combination. I only want 1 count per day, the other entries on that same day should be regarded as duplicates and should be ignored. "DISTINCT" should be able to accomplish that I believe, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: They second chunck of code that has the derived table (SELECT DISTINCT seller....) should handle that situation.  Basically instead of generating the row number on the table directly you will need to do it on the derived table instead which eliminates the duplicates.  If my answer works for you please up vote and accept  it so others know that you got what you needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Matt, ran into an issue when prod_id's can be used and new (prod_cond). 
I tried to solve it by adding prod_cond to the if statement in the query, but that still doesn't work properly. The streaks get broken up when there is 1 prod_id listed a new and 1 as used. Example here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a2bd/2

Comment: @dean2020 I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the addition of prod_cond  are you wanting to ignore the change in prod_cond if so add prod_cond ahead of DateCol in the order by of the derived table.  In you want to break the streak then same thing you will need to change up the order by and allow for datetime but dong so will mean you wont be aggregated by day so you would need to use date diff of max and min of each group, so you should create a group row number to make that easy.